# What is the setting to on the info.plist to prevent the app from running on an iPod-touch?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod-touch

I cant use the 'requires call capability' since it need to be compatible with iPads.

Comment: What makes it runnable on an iPad but not on an iPod touch?

Comment: @BoltClock Two words ... The Client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        iPhone 1G:  A-GPS,  accelerometer,  camera      --        --     
        iPhone 3G:  A-GPS,  accelerometer,  camera      --        --     
 iPhone Simulator:  A-GPS,  accelerometer     --        --        --     
       iPhone 3GS:  A-GPS,  accelerometer,  camera   compass,     --      
         iPhone 4:  A-GPS,  accelerometer,  camera,  compass,  gyroscope  
             iPad:  A-GPS,  accelerometer     --     compass,     --     
           iPad 2:  A-GPS,  accelerometer,  camera,  compass,  gyroscope  
    iPod Touch 1G:   --     accelerometer     --        --        --     
    iPod Touch 2G:   --     accelerometer     --        --        --     
    iPod Touch 3G:   --     accelerometer     --        --        --     
    iPod Touch 4G:   --     accelerometer,  camera,     --     gyroscope
```

So try something like

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
 <string>gps</string>
  <string>location-services</string>
</array>
```